# Multiple AssociatedControlID's on label

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webusercontrol

Is it possible to associate more than one ID to an "AssociatedControlID" field on an asp.net label?

Example:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblColour" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtColourFront, txtColourBack, txtColour" Text="ColourFront" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtColourFront" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtColourBack" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtColour" runat="server" />
```

Comment: I know this is old, but I came across this looking for an answer to a similar question I had. I found the answer given in another question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004307/two-input-fields-inside-one-label Using a fieldset and legend would probably be the best route in this scenario to group the textboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No its not possible.

This will be rendered as the `for` attribute for a `label` element in HTML.

This element doesn't accept multiple `for` attributes.