# How to find the closest label to an input?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, css-selectors

I have a few `input`s that have a `label` above them. I want to find the closest `label` for each of them. The issue is some of the `input`s don't have a direct `label` above them.

Initially I had this:

```
let el = document.querySelector(`label[for="${this.element.id}"]`)
```

This worked for all case except some rare cases where I had two `input`s in one line, like `test` and `test2`. How can I get the `test` `label` for the `test2` `input`?

```
<div>
      <label for="test">Interval</label><br>
      <input min="0.1" id="test" placeholder="Min" step="0.1" type="number">
      <input min="0.1" id="test2" placeholder="Max" step="0.1" type="number">

      <label for="limit">Limit</label><br>
      <input id="limit" step="1" type="number">
</div>
```

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004307/two-input-fields-inside-one-label. you shouldn't use a single label with 2 inputs

Comment: I know but the only reason I want to get the closest label is too append an icon to it. So I m not using 1 label for 2 inputs just need it to show a pending call status @OvidiuDolha

Comment: @OvidiuDolha your link is a valid thing, however the situation seems different, as the label is here not wrapped around the inputs. Technically the OP's code is semantically correct, and the label is associated to only one input by its id

Comment: @HeelMega Can we assume the right libel is always situated **before** the input? If so, maybe you should rephrase your title, as in your example case the label you want is not the closest (it's the one under)

Comment: @Kaddath yes, absolutely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [aria-labelledby](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-labelledby_attribute) attribute for this instead. The `aria-labelledby` attribute establishes relationships between objects and their label(s), and its value should be one or more element IDs.

Here, we can assume `test2` is actually what you have in the code like `this.element.id`. Using that we can get the `aria-labelledby` attribute value using [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) method. Then we can simply pass that to `document.querySelector` to get the closest label w.r.t the input id.

```js
let input = document.querySelector(`#test2`)
let labelId = input.getAttribute('aria-labelledby')

let el1 = document.querySelector(`label[id="${labelId}"]`)
el1.style.color = "green"
```

```html
<div>
  <label id="interval">Interval</label><br>
  <input min="0.1" id="test" placeholder="Min" step="0.1" type="number" aria-labelledby="interval">
  <input min="0.1" id="test2" placeholder="Max" step="0.1" type="number" aria-labelledby="interval">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I made a function `searchLabel` for you!

```js
function searchLabel(inputElem) {
  var elem = inputElem;
  while (true) {
    if (elem.tagName == "LABEL") {
      break;
    }
    if (elem == null) {
      break;
    }
    elem = elem.previousSibling;
  }
  return elem;
}
console.log(searchLabel(document.getElementById("test2")));
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <label for="test">Interval</label><br>
  <input min="0.1" id="test" placeholder="Min" step="0.1" type="number">
  <input min="0.1" id="test2" placeholder="Max" step="0.1" type="number">

  <label for="limit">Limit</label><br>
  <input id="limit" step="1" type="number">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the nearest parent label element in the DOM using a little manual DOM traversal like so:

```js
function nearestParentLabel(inputId) {
  let input = document.getElementById(inputId);
  let label = input.previousSibling;
  while (label != null && label.tagName != "LABEL") {
    label = label.previousSibling;
  }
  return label;
}

console.log(
  nearestParentLabel("test"), // returns "test" label
  nearestParentLabel("test2"), // returns "test" label
  nearestParentLabel("limit"), // returns "limit" label
);
```

```html
<div>
      <label for="test">Interval</label><br>
      <input min="0.1" id="test" placeholder="Min" step="0.1" type="number">
      <input min="0.1" id="test2" placeholder="Max" step="0.1" type="number">

      <label for="limit">Limit</label><br>
      <input id="limit" step="1" type="number">
</div>
```